# Unable to access Redux array state from component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to access my Redux groceries array from my grocery list component, and when I try to access the state with this.props.groceries, it returns 'undefined'. I'm still trying to wrap my head around some Redux concepts, but I think I'm really close. In my store.js, I'm logging

```
store.subscribe(() => {
    console.log('store changed', store.getState());
});
```

And getState() is displaying my correct groceries array, with all the groceries inside it. I'm just not sure how to access this state from my groceries list component. Thanks!

Overview of my GroceryList component:

```
        import { connect } from "react-redux";
        import { bindActionCreators, createStore } from 'redux';
        import * as groceryActions from '../../redux/actions/grocery-actions';

        class GroceryList extends Component {
            constructor(props) {
                super(props);
                this.state = {
                };
            }
            addGroceryToList() {
                this.props.addGrocery(newGroceryItem);
                console.log(this.props.groceries); //Logs undefined
            }
            render() {
               return(
                  //something
               )
            }
        }

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    groceries: state.groceries.groceries
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>
  bindActionCreators(
    { addGrocery: groceryActions.addGrocery, },
    dispatch
  )

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(GroceryList);
```

Grocery action:

```
let groceryIndex = 0;

export const addGrocery = grocery => dispatch => {
    dispatch({
        type: 'ADD_GROCERY',
        id: groceryIndex++,
        grocery
    });
};
```

Grocery reducer:

```
export const groceries = (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "ADD_GROCERY":
            return [
                ...state,
                grocery(action.grocery, action),
            ];
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export const grocery = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "ADD_GROCERY":
            return {
                id: action.id,
                grocery: action.grocery,
            };
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Reducer combiner:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

import { groceries } from './grocery-reducer';

const reducer = combineReducers({
    groceries: groceries,
});

export default reducer;
```

Store

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import reducer from './reducers';

if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
    global.window = {}
}

const enhancer = compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk),
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__
    ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
    : f => f
);

/* eslint-disable no-underscore-dangle */
const store = createStore(
    reducer,
    {}, // initial state
    enhancer
)

store.subscribe(() => {
    console.log('store changed', store.getState());
});

/* eslint-enable */

export default store
```

App.js

```
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import * as groceryActions from "./src/redux/actions/grocery-actions";
import store from './src/redux/store';

class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Layout />
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}

export default (App);
```

Comment: It's likely your mapsStateToProps is making an incorrect reference within your GroceryList component file.

    `const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
        groceries: state.groceries.groceries
    });`

Shouldn't it be `state.groceries` only?

Comment: ahhhhh thanks for catching that hahahah. Works with state.groceries. @zavjs

Comment: Hah! That happens all the time to me. It's always good to have an external eye to catch these things. Glad I could help